# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException?

Tags: java, android, ssl, ca

I'm trying to connect to a WCF server using HTTPS connection (UrlHttpsConnection class) and always get the error "Trust anchor for certification path not found".
I found thousands examples on the Web about that issue but nothing that really helps me.

My WCF service works with a certificate signed by an internal CA that has been added to the list of trusted CAs on my smartphone. If I call the url https://myserver/myservice/test from Chrome on my smartphone, I no longer have warning, the certificate is considered as valid. From my app, I keep getting the error message.

Do you know why my app does not consider the server certificate as valid while Chrome does ? How can I fix that ?

For security reasons, I don't want ignore the SSL verification.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: because when call api that time pass ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way but i used retrofit for api calling..

```
  public class ApiClient {
//public final static String BASE_URL = "https://prod.appowiz.com/app/services/";
public final static String BASE_URL_SECURE = "Pass your url";

public static ApiClient apiClient;

private Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient(Context context) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_SECURE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
 public static Retrofit getStore() {
    if (storeRetrofit == null) {
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {

            }


            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {

            }


            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }};

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).hostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
                    .build();
            storeRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_SECURE)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e1) {
            CustomLogHandler.printErrorlog(e1);
        }

    }

    return storeRetrofit;
}
```

for api calling create interface..

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@POST("device/add_device_name")
Call<AddDeviceNameVo> addDeviceName(@Body JsonObject body);

 }
```

called api into activity or fragment like this way..

```
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getStore().create(ApiInterface.class);
```